# Увеличить раздел диска ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

как добавить место из datastore-data в ubuntu-vg?
[image: data]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: В общем случае - `lvresize --extents +100%FREE --resizefs /dev/xxxx/root` должен отработать.